# Name and how to care for this plant?

Tags: identification

Can someone please tell me what plant is this and what kind of environment it likes to be in? I noticed the browning tips does it require more dry/humid environment?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bromeliad; water sparingly ,mostly in the center of the plant. It will tend to hold water. Temperature above 40 F. I have not noticed them to be sensitive to humidity.